# How to get the directory my artifact is extracted to during a release step?

Tags: asp.net, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm using VSTS to deploy asp.net web applications.  We're changing up how we deploy transformed web.config files, as we got burned during a recent production post when the files were not correctly transformed during the "IIS Web App Deploy.  Our new plan is to use the CodeAssassin.ConfigTransform" nuget task, and all of our config transforms are transformed as part of the build.  These can be validated/inspected by our developers locally, and are incorporated into the build artifact.

So to my question,
Basically in my build artifact, under the root of my web project, we'll find transformed web.config files, e.g. web.dev.config.transformed, web.qa.config.transformed, web.dev.config.transformed, etc.

As a new step in my release process, per environment, I want to copy the correct file within my artifact, before the "IIS Web App Deploy" task pushes the change out to the webserver. At a very basic level after all variable replacements, the copy command would look something like this.

```
copy-item ?????web.dev.config.transformed -Destination ?????web.config
```

I need to replace ????? with the path which my artifact has been extracted, e.g.

```
C:\vstsagent\A1\_work\r1\a\temp_web_package_7996773376015784\Content\C_C\VSTS_agent\_work\6\s\My.Web.Project\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\
```

I've looked at every build/release variable (thanks Gian Maria [Dump all environment variables during a TFS / VSTS Build](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2017/08/04/dump-all-environment-variables-during-a-tfs-vsts-build/)), and I see nothing like this path that I can access from a variable.

I'm obviously missing something simple here...as other tasks have this information available to them?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I ended up abandoning this effort due to the complexity of digging into the web deploy package zip.  I'm using web deploy parameters now that I specify within the variables of the VSTS project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the **temp_web_package_XXX.zip** file is generated by **IIS Web App Deploy task** if enabled **File Transforms & Variable Substitution** (Extract your package > Do transform > Archive files to temp package (temp_web_package_xxx.zip)), so you don’t need to do with the temp package files.

Secondly, you just need to do with your package files (e.g. extract package file > Copy files to folder) and the path likes `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/[build definition name]/[Artifact name (Specified in Publish Build Artifacts task)]/*.zip`.

You can remove the source path structure from package by specifying `/P:PackageTempRootDir=""` MSBuild arguments in **Visual Studio Build** or **MSBuild** task. For dotnet core project, using **.NET Core** (Command: Publish; Check Zip Published Projects option) task.

After that, the folder structure likes `[WebApp]\Content\D_C\PackageTmp`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable you're looking for is `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`.

This will give you the first part of the path. After that you can append your own folders and files like this:

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\My.Web.Project\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\
```

You can also use the [Copy File task](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-files) (v2) in your Build Definition and then check Flatten Files. That will remove the directories you don't need from the path in your artifact. That will make it easier to work with the artifact in your release

Comment: But where would this value come from (in my example above)?  temp_web_package_7996773376015784

Comment: @Wouter de Kort Does the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) work if i use it in a typescript file for a custom task?  I.e. `let buildsPath = $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`

Comment: @xtreampb when building a NodeJS task (with JavaScript or TypeScript), you can access properties as environment variables with process.env["INPUT_SAMPLESTRING"]. See https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/master/node/docs/stepbystep.md for more information.